# Where can i find free sounds to use in my application?

Tags: sound

We can't use copyrighted sounds so where can i found non copyrighted sounds?
For example http://openclipart.org/ provides non copyrighted images.

But what about sounds? Small duration sounds like a bell or something..
Maybe the sounds that are provided from a music maker program like MAGIX MUSIC MAKER 18, can i use them? I read the terms of use in their site but didn't understand if i can use these sounds...

Thanks for any answer...

Comment: I found some royalty-free music here: http://animation.about.com/od/referencematerials/a/freemusicsound.htm -- I'm not sure about redistribution though.

Comment: well i see they are not free...

Comment: they are royalty-free, as in "you don't have to pay to use or include them" -- Here's some probably CC 3.0 content http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Content_Directories -- http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Audio#Featured_Audio_Sites

Comment: sorry but i can't see how you can download sounds like a bell. I only find beats and russian sites... So i ask again.. Can i use the sounds that are provided from a music maker?

Answer (score 2):

[SoundSnag.com](http://soundsnag.com) has some free sounds and you can make sound requests in their forum